# How do you get a part of webpage from remote by using php?

Tags: php

Id like to get a part of webpage. 
Let me show you what id like to do.

For example, http:// www.xxxxxx.com/page=2

As you can see there is a list, and this list shows 50 ads. Please ignore other ones. Every ads have an unique id in their links.

for example:

> http:// xxx.com/-iid-155546130

the id number is : 155546130

Okay, id like to get unique id numbers from that page, and echo them to the screen. So, i need to get 50 unique ids from that page. Only id numbers.

well, could you please kindly give me some advice? which functions should i use? how can i do that job?

Regards.

Comment: Well you should start by reading the terms of use, which will enlighten you that you're trying to engage in criminal activity. "OLX grants you a limited, revocable, nonexclusive license to access the Service for your own personal use. This license does not include: (a) access to the Service by Posting Agents; or (b) any collection, aggregation, copying, duplication, display or derivative use of the Service nor any use of data mining, robots, spiders, or similar data gathering and extraction tools for any purpose unless expressly permitted by OLX."

Comment: link was just for example. your comment is not helpfull

Comment: Sorry Andrew, took it literally, in that case andrewk's comment is relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetch the page with:

```
$html = file_get_contents($url);  // or curl if you like it cumbersome
```

And use a regex to get the numbers:

```
preg_match_all("/-iid-(\d+)/", $html, $m);  // could be more precise
print_r($m[1]);
```

Comment: thank you. such a perfect answer. you ve been so helpfull for me. great answer. thanks again for million times. regards

Comment: I haven't tested this but some "more precise" Regex could be `http://.*olx\.co\.uk/.*-iid-(\d+)`

Answer (score 0):

You will have to get the HTML and parse it for those IDs. In that case you will have to know exactly where those IDs exist. You can use regular expressions to find links to other pages(websites) and then look for IDs.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a [built-in DOM parser](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php). Poke around the class of functions to reveal what you're looking for.